# Git Master Branch Containing other branch info

Tags: git, merge, version-control

This might be a default behavior but it's giving me hard time to understand.
I always thought a branch must be one line, without other "branches".
I made the following experiment:

1. Init a git repo.
2. Commit twice(m1,m2) on master branch
3. Checkout a new branch named "dev"
4. Commit twice(d1,d2) on dev branch.
5. Checkout master
6. Commit twice(m3,m4)

Now the branch looks like below

[image: Before Merge]

From my understanding, there are 4 checkins in master branch, 2 checkins in dev branch.

Now I perform the following operations:

1. Merge dev branch (git merge dev)

The branch looks like below:

[image]

I would think that the master branch is the green one, it contains 5 commits.
The dev branch is the purple one, it contains 4 commits.

Actually, in master branch, I use `git log` to check the commits, it actually has 7 commits. Which confuses me.

Can someone help explain?

Comment: A commit is on a branch if it is reachable from the branch head, there is no information in the commit about which branch it was originally committed on. From this you should also understand that if a commit is reachable from multiple branch heads then the commit is said to be on all of those branches at the same time. It is not more on one branch than on another.

Comment: So that means that all those commits are on the master branch, and if dev is still on d2, d1 and d2 is also on the dev branch, as is m1 and m2.

Comment: You might want to read about [What a Branch Is](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log` lists all commits reachable from the given ref (or HEAD if no refs are given). The 7 commits you see *are* reachable. You might need to give log some other specific parameters if you want to see only parts of the tree. (Check [the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification) there are great examples)

Also, your surprise can be a consequence of a misunderstanding about branches in git. No commit in the tree *belongs* to any branch. The whole tree can be accessed through different points, and branches are just shortcuts to point at *one commit*.

Comment: I thought I must accidentally displayed the other branch info. So I setup a remote Git Repo, push master branch into that repo. And cloned this project to another directory(ensure no other branches exist). Inside that directory, I used git log/visualization tool and I can still see the check-ins of other branch.

Comment: @Bai Bing No "check-ins" (I guess you meant commits) are *of other branch* or *of master branch*, that's what I tried to explain. They are reachable from a point or they're not.

Comment: Thanks! I think I just misunderstood the concept of "branch".  The visualization tools are showing the branch as a line, which confuses me. Thanks for your explanation!